# ADODB connection with SQL Server, SQL "Group By" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a module in JavaScript that makes a ADODB connection with SQL Server. That connection works fine for many SQL queries but it fails when the SQL statements holds the "Group By" function. It always returns 0 records.

Before using it in JavaScript I always test the query with HEIDISQL on SQL server and it works fine.

I tried different ways of presenting it in JavaScript:

1.

```
select NAME, sum(PLAN) as 'total' from dbo.TEST group by NAME
```

2.

```
select NAME, sum(PLAN) from dbo.TEST group by NAME
```

3.

```
SELECT [dbo].[TEST].[NAME], sum([dbo].[TEST].[PLAN_TOT]) FROM [dbo].[TEST] GROUP BY [dbo].[TEST].[NAME]
```

With and without quotes around the field name etc, the result is always 0 records.

Does anyone have experience with this phenomenon?
Is it impossible to use the "Group By" option in JavaScript on SQL server?
Is there a work-around other than using a stored procedure?
Any other thoughts?

NB: I'm aware of the security issues of using JavaScript on SQL server.

Comment: You're mixing up the table name...

Comment: Is it maybe because you haven't specified an alias for the SUM. Try SELECT [dbo].[TEST].[NAME], sum([dbo].[TEST].[PLAN_TOT]) [SumPlanTot] FROM [dbo].[TEST] GROUP BY [dbo].[TEST].[NAME]